# How to add event on HTML list's bullets?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

How to add event on HTML list's bullets? is it possible?

Comment: what do you intend to do? can you *clarify* or at least put some more detail on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ...and post your "HTML list's bullets" code...

Comment: What event do you want to listen to?

Comment: i create multiple-choice questions and i use ul list for that. but instead put radio button i prefer the users click on bullets by add event to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to handle click events or something else such as DOMSubtreeModified?
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/quant/At7xd/

HTML:

```
<h1>Some simple events</h1>
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<button>Add Item</button>​
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#list").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e) {
        console.log("DOMSubtreeModified event", e);
        $("h1").toggleClass("crazy");
    });
    $("#list").on("click", "li", function(e) {
        console.log("Clicked on an li:", $(e.currentTarget).html(), e);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("button").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("Clicked on button", e);            
        $("#list").append("<li>Item " + ($("#list > li").size() + 1) + "</li>");
    } );
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').on( "click" , function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function(event){
    // do something
  });
}
```